# How to create a fat jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar, spark-java

With SpringBoot, you have the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, but what is the equivalent with the neat Java Spark framework?

IntelliJ creates a Maven project and I added the spark dependency, but running the install goal, I get a 5 KB jar with no manifest. Not an executable jar.

The `pom.xml` created thus far is as follows:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sparkdemo</groupId>
  <artifactId>sparkdemo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0 </version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>sparkdemo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
          <optimize>true</optimize>
          <debug>true</debug>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Would appreciate any suggestions....Thanks!

Comment: I'm not wholly familiar with spark, but since you have maven and this is a pom, this sounds like a job for the [Maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html).

Comment: maven assembly plugin would help, but if you have sources you can always execute it as maven task and maven would take care of dependencies

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need here is an executable jar that will not only contain your classes, but also classes from all your dependencies. 
For that you can use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html).

See the sample code below.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>org.sample.App</mainClass>     // specify your main class here
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      [...]
</project>
```

Then, run `mvn package` and the executable jar should be located in the folder `target` (with a name like `ProjectName-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`).

Comment: This works fine! Thank you!!!

Did I just use the wrong Maven Intellij Setup?

I thought Maven took care of this stuff so I must have created the project using too basic a Maven setup?

Comment: By default, maven will not package any dependant jars when you build and package your application. Maven was designed more for J2EE purposes. If your application contains a main class and you would like to execute it (jar that you generate) then you will need all your dependencies to be also present on your classpath (application having main class). This is not the default behavior offered by maven. Hence you will have to explicitly tell maven to build an executable jar with all the dependencies also being packaged with your application jar.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for maven assembly plugin

Add this in the plugin section and run `mvn package`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>assemble-all</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```