# How HBase add its dependency jars and use HADOOP_CLASSPATH

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

[48. HBase, MapReduce, and the CLASSPATH](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hbase.mapreduce.classpath)

> By default, MapReduce jobs deployed to a MapReduce cluster do not have access to either the HBase configuration under $HBASE_CONF_DIR or the HBase classes.

> To give the MapReduce jobs the access they need, you could add hbase-site.xml_to _$HADOOP_HOME/conf and add HBase jars to the $HADOOP_HOME/lib directory. You would then need to copy these changes across your cluster. Or you could edit $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh and add hbase dependencies to the HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable. Neither of these approaches is recommended because it will pollute your Hadoop install with HBase references. It also requires you restart the Hadoop cluster before Hadoop can use the HBase data.

> The recommended approach is to let HBase add its dependency jars and use HADOOP_CLASSPATH or -libjars.

I'm learning how HBase interacts with MapReduce

I know what the above two ways mean, but I don't know how to configure the recommended way

Could anyone tell me how to configure it in the recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs show, prior to running `hadoop jar`, you can `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(hbase classpath)` and you can use `hadoop jar ... -libjars [...]`

---

The true recommended way would be to [bundle your HBase dependencies as an Uber JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41493611/2308683) in your mapreduce application

The only caveat is that you need to ensure that your project uses the same/compatible `hbase-mapreduce` client versions as the server.

That way, you don't need any extra configuration, except maybe specifying the `hbase-site.xml`